# Google Cloud / APIs: Quota Circumvention via multiple projects

Tags: youtube-api

I manage several projects, each project includes several API Clients (Android App, iOS App, PWA and backend server).

Glossary from [yt API terms](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms):

> - "API Client" means a website or software application (including a mobile application) developed by you that accesses or uses the YouTube API Services.
> - "API Project" means the project created in the Google Developer Console that is required for API Client(s) to access and use the YouTube API Services.

Following [yt API terms](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms) I `must create exactly one (1) API Project for that API Client. Those API Credentials are intended to be used exclusively by the associated API Client, which means that you must not use that one (1) API Project for multiple API Clients.`. Then I understand that I should create one API Project for Android App, one more for iOS App, etc.

But I've recently received following email from Google:

> We have recently detected your Google Cloud / APIs Projects have been circumventing our quota restrictions via multiple projects acting as one and appears to be violating YouTube API Terms of Service (III.D.1.c).
>
> To fix the problem please delete all projects using YouTube API usage except for one project you wish to keep active

Then if I delete API Projects and keep a single one for all my API Clients, that means I should use one API Project for multiple API Clients, that is forbidden by terms.

What's the best way to follow ?

Comment: What I understood from your quoted text is that you are to create only one API Project that uses YouTube API Services, which you can use for your API Client(s) (take note of the "(s)") to access YouTube API Services. Your quoted text tells you that you can have multiple API Clients accessing YouTube API Services through one API Project.

Comment: I have the same warning email. What have you done about this? Did you delete other projects and kept only 1?

Comment: No I didn't, at the moment the service continue working, and I continue to not understand what should I do to respect terms... Let me know if you find a solution